# Cell value when given column title and value from row

Tags: python, excel, csv, lookup-tables

I have an excel file/csv that has both Column and row titles(row 1 is all titles, column A is all row titles). I was hoping to use dictreader to return the value of the (x,y) coordinate when I supply the column and row.

Eventually, I went to be able to give multiple columns and a single row and it will combine the value in each given column for that row. But I will start with baby steps as I currently can't even return the first value I want. Here is a small sample of my excel file/CSV:

```
PinName RF_Switch_TX1   RF_Switch_TX2   RF_Switch_TX3   RF_Switch_TX3_Scope1    RF_Switch_TX3_Scope2

DM_D_0  1255,1266,1311                                  1154,1105,  
DM_D_1  1256,1266,1311                                  1154,1105,
DQS                     1101,1161        1105                                   1153,1105
```

How can i build a function that if supplied Pin Name "DM_D_1" and the column title "RF_Switch_TX3_Scope1" it would return 1154,1105,

I was hoping to just use dictreader but do I need to build an iterative function that searches through my file?

Answer (score 2):

Would using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) be an acceptable approach? (The initial question mentioned Python, but now it seems not to.) I'm not sure that this is the most idiomatic use of Pandas, but it seems to do what you want to do.

**The data**

I put this into a CSV file.

```
PinName,RF_Switch_TX1, RF_Switch_TX2,RF_Switch_TX3,RF_Switch_TX3_Scope1,RF_Switch_TX3_Scope2
DM_D_0,"1255,1266,1311",,,"1154,1105,",
DM_D_1,"1256,1266,1311",,,"1154,1105,",
DQS,,"1101,1161",1105,,"1153,1105"
```

**Some code**

```
from pandas import read_csv

df = read_csv("/Users/igow/Desktop/so_data.csv")
df = df.set_index(['PinName'])

def get_value(row, col):
    return df[col][row]

print(get_value(col='RF_Switch_TX3_Scope1', row='DM_D_1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put data in CSV or at least specify the delimiter properly, then you can do the following:

```
  In [56]: q = StringIO('''PinName,RF_Switch_TX1, RF_Switch_TX2,RF_Switch_TX3,RF_Switch_TX3_Scope1,RF_Switch_TX3_Scope2
   ....: DM_D_0,"1255,1266,1311",,,"1154,1105,",
   ....: DM_D_1,"1256,1266,1311",,,"1154,1105,",
   ....: DQS,,"1101,1161",1105,,"1153,1105"''')

In [57]: df1 = pd.read_csv(q,)

In [58]: df1.loc[df1['PinName'] == 'DM_D_1']['RF_Switch_TX3_Scope1'].values[0]
Out[58]: '1154,1105,'

In [59]:
```